# OpenMP speed up loss

Tags: performance, openmp

I used OpenMP to speed up my program which is looking for a pattern in text.

**Question:**
Why there is speed up loss on six and ten threads and then it increases on eight and twelve(chart below)? I thought that speed up line should be more straight (more threads = speed up increase). I tried to use various text size, algorithms and number of blocks but chart did not change.

**Program/device information**

- text is divided in 10000 blocks
- omp_max_threads() returns 8
- text size is 40MB
- processor has 4 cores

**Code**

```
double start = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel for shared(pat, blockTxt, numOfBlocks,patSize) private (i) reduction(+:result)
for (i = 0; i < numOfBlocks; i++) {
    result += Alghorithm().naive(pat, blockTxt[i], patSize, blockTxt[i].size());
}


double end = omp_get_wtime();
```

**Chart**

[image: Speed up]

Comment: "more threads = speed up increase" Not really. More threads=more computing power (up to the number of cores). More threads=more cache (again up to the number of cores), but more threads is also more management, synchronization, etc. With 4 cores, you should have a good speedup with 4 threads, maybe 8 if you can hide some latency by thread switching (and it is what happens as you have a superlinear (>4) speedup with 8 threads). A besides that, it is difficult to give an answer for the small variations.

Comment: Any way you can provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2):

The idea you seem to have that "more threads = speed up increase" is fundamentally wrong. What you should strive for is using the hardware capability you have as fully and effectively as possible in order to reduce the time it takes to solve your problem.

Sometime (often) that translates into parallelizing your problem and distributing the work between the various processing units your computer(s) provide. But most of the time (not always, but the counter examples are quite rare), overloading your processing units (the cores basically) with more than one thread or process each, will only slow-down the overall computation. So your goals, for efficient parallel processing, are as follows:

1. Divide the work / problem into smaller pieces that can be solved as independently from each-other as possible, while adding as little as possible extra work to recombine them
2. Distribute these smaller tasks to the various processing units you have access to in a manner such that:

   - All of them are busy
   - They all have work to do that will complete in a time that is as even as possible between them
   - The overhead of having distributed the work and to put it back together is as small as possible
   - And most importantly, to make sure that the part of the work that hasn't been parallelized is a small as possible

In your case, since you have 4 cores available, what you want is to get them 4 busy, with about the same amount of work for each.

I don't know whether each of the small individual calls to your search algorithm are of identical size, but is they are, then the likelihood of having an optimal overall speedup with 4 threads is the highest.

Now, as you have actually 2 hardware threads per core, there's still the chance that each of them might permit a better use of the hardware at hand. It isn't usually the case for problems that are computationally intensive, but yours apparently isn't too so since indeed, when using 8 threads, the speedup gets slightly better: it reaches 4 which is basically the absolute limit you shouldn't be able to go above (as you have 4 cores).

Why does 6 get you a slow down? Well, if you look at what your goals must be, you should realise that with 6 OpenMP threads to divide between 4 cores, you create a load imbalance between these cores and, due to the synchronization that the finalization of the parallelization induces, some of the cores will have to wait for the others to finish the extra work they have at the end. And this waiting is enough to cripple your overall efficiency. Idem for 10 threads.

Finally, as I said, you're lucky enough that your parallelization overhead is small enough so that 8 threads gives you a perfect speedup, and even 12 (which is evenly divided by 4 cores)... But again, that only gives you a speedup of 4, which is fundamentally the upper limit of what your hardware is capable of.

Comment: As you can see OP's work *is* divided, and there are 4 *hyper-threaded* cores, so a noticeable speedup (around 30%) between 4 and 8 threads can be expected. As to why it's not the case remains a mystery that cannot be solved given the information provided.

Comment: As explained, when the work isn't too computationally intensive, hyper-threading might help. The reasons can be multiple: help the overall load balancing, provide with more data access requests permitting to better overlap data fetching with actual computations (this one would be my bets bet here), some cache effect due to data decomposition, etc. All in all, many things can happen, but the positive effect is quite rare. Here, the OP is lucky.

Comment: If you are looking for the larger speedups from overlapping computations with TLB misses,it will work only when a stalled and an unstalled thread  are on the same core, and all cores are seeing similar behavior at all times.  Several years ago, CPUs introduced hardware acceleration for "predicted" DTLB misses, partly on account of Windows not handling them as well as linux.  This also has the effect of reducing the advantage of hyperthreading for this situation.